# While doing the `dry-run` how can I pass the `record` as a parameter and `empty map` as a `initial storage`?

Tags: storage, bigmap, dry-run

I'm having the following sample contract, where I'm trying to pass the `record` value as a parameter and also want to pass `empty map` as storage; can someone help me?

```
type string_rec = {
  a : string; 
  b : string
}

type parameter =
  Add of string_rec
| Get of string_rec

type storage = (string, string_rec) map

type return = operation list * storage

let add (store, k : storage * string_rec) : storage = 
  Map.add("abc" : string) (k) store

let get (store, k : storage * string_rec) : storage = 
  Map.add("abc" : string) (k) store

let main (action, store : parameter * storage) : return =
 ([] : operation list),
 (match action with
   Add n -> add (store, n)
 | Get n -> get (store, n))
```

Answer (score 0):

(1) a record will be translated into a nested pair-structure, so you need to have something like this `(Pair "string 1" "string 2")`.

(2) you can't *pass* a storage to an existing contract. You can only initialize a contract storage during its *origination*. An empty map is written as `{}`.